# Why do people get denied boarding for being late, when the plane is still on the tarmac for many minutes after?

Tags: airports, airport-security

Once in a while I get posts in my Facebook newsfeed about people complaining that they are denied boarding for being late but can still see their plane on the tarmac.

I guess it is people seeing the plane 'idle' on the tarmac but denied boarding (for being late) that makes them start making assumptions and accusations.

Knowing what goes on behind the scenes might help people appreciate being on time.

What's going on / preventing people from being allowed to run on and take their seat, assuming an air-bridge?

Comment: This question is not too broad.

Comment: I was expecting something like the "Flight Planning" in this article: http://blog.flysafair.co.za/why-you-cant-check-in-late/ but more detailed, like citing regulations and mentioning things that layman know nothing about. If different airports will have different things going on, that would be even more interesting to know. Sorry, i don't know how to narrow down the question.

Comment: For the passenger, the actual deadline is when the manifest is closed, but everyone says 'door'.

Comment: Something that doesn't seem to have been mentioned is that the flight bridges can cost up to AU$1000 a minute to rent (in Australia with similar elsewhere), with any delay costing the airlines significantly. The fact that luggage has to be put on the plane with a meal for you as well as a print out of the customer manifest, any passenger being late is to cause significant delay in these preparative processes. By the sounds of it, the people on your feed complaining about getting denied boarding (in order to not delay a plane full of people) only have themselves to blame.

Comment: Yes and yes, Coder! That unmentioned fact is among what i was hoping to find! They see themselves as the victim and blame everything else EXCEPT themselves! If only they realized the consequences towards themselves AND others (airlines system, flight schedule, other passengers, etc) for being late, and what would happen if late passengers were allowed to board. I feel sorry for the staff who might have a bad time managing them, and the airline system they're badmouthing about. This is the most i can do for all parties involved. :'(

Comment: May be people do not want to take any chance of missing the flight..because there are many rules and regulations for entering into the flight from check in to sit in the flight..and it will take at least 1 hour in completing all the formalities and all..that is the reason people reach the airport earlier..

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder $60,000/hour for an airbridge? I think most airlines would be out of business if they had to pay that

Comment: @Berwyn That was the price at Perth Airport when I worked there last. They may have changed, but that was what I was being told at the time and it doesn't seem outrageous at places like Heathrow, JFK or Narita where some departures are 2 minutes apart. A 30 minute delay could mean you miss your place in the departure queue delaying your plane longer and other planes later in the queue as they figure out how to juggle your lateness into the schedule.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder https://www.perthairport.com.au/-/media/Files/CORPORATE/Work-with-us/Airport-charges/NON-PSA-Aero-Charges-Schedule-01-JUL-2016.pdf?la=en Not sure where you get $1000/minute from there. Says $10/tonne per day which is, say, $3000/day for a 747

Comment: @Berwyn You are comparing a parking bay to airbridge usage. According the document you link to, Aircraft Storage means aircraft at Perth Airport that do not conduct any flight operations within a 14 day rolling period and are parked on a Perth Airport Pty Ltd operated apron or bay for a continuous period of 5 or more days. So that doesn't apply to aircraft using the airbridges. The number I was told is likely factoring in ground staff, catering and other supporting activities on top on the fixed airport fees (DOM ~$1000 per 52 pax, INT ~$1000 per 70 pax [for only terminal (airbridge) usage]).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Those are the commercial flight costs for all possible fees as far as I can see. If you can tell me how that adds up to $60k for an hour, I'd be interested in knowing how you calculate it

Comment: @Berwyn Those are the AIRPORT commercial fees, not each airlines operating costs. As I have now mentioned twice, this was the figure I was told by both the ramp operator and the duty manager at the time. I would like to know the full breakdown of a carriers' by the minute costs as well, but as I am not in corporate, thus I am at a loss as to the inner budget projections of an airline.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder "flight bridges can cost up to AU$1000 a minute to rent". Let's just leave it there. I was only curious how you came up with that number. No offence

Comment: @Berwyn I thought it somewhat dubious when I heard it too. Nevertheless, I heard it from 2 separate people, so I assumed it correct. Just from the figures in that document though, I can only see one off payments per aircraft / pax. Maybe it costs the airport because one bridge will not be able to be used (and thus charged)?

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36521/how-do-i-find-how-much-it-costs-to-park-a-b747-at-an-airbridge-in-perth ;)

Comment: @Berwyn That question would account for the airport fees as part of this question, but not airline operating costs associated with both the airbridge staffing and ground operations. It is good that someone understood that somewhat cryptic payments summary though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simplest terms, once the boarding is completed and the boarding door closed, a number of pre-flight procedures are started based on the number of people on board.  Performance calculations based on weight and balance being an obvious one.  Additionally, the final manifests must be transmitted to various Authorities.

Changing the number of people on board requires these procedures to be re-done and that takes time causing everyone, including the other passengers, to wait.

It is also quite possible that the seats assigned to the late arriving passengers have been given to others so there would be no where for them to sit anyway.

For clarity, the staff *can* return an aircraft to the gate to board additional passengers it's just far too disruptive to do so.  They will however return to the gate to deplane a passenger who does not want to fly as that is viewed as a risk on several levels.